# c# multiple events and return codes

Tags: c#

I have the following event:

```
public delegate bool AccountEvent(string AccountId);
public static event AccountEvent AccountCreationCallback;
```

so, in the code I have this:

```
Users.AccountCreationCallback += CreateWallet;

bool CreateWallet(string AccountId)
{
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

and the event is handled this way:

```
if (AccountCreationCallback != null)
{
    return AccountCreationCallback(User._id);
}

return true;
```

so, if there is an event AND it fails, I return false; otherwise, true.

now, the question is what happens if I have multiple events?

```
Users.AccountCreationCallback += CreateWallet;
Users.AccountCreationCallback += AttachAddress;
```

and what I'm really trying to do is be able to have several events and stop the call chain if a single one returns false.

can this be implemented with the c# event system?

Comment: [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There's no need to define your own event, you can just use `Func<string, bool>` to have a delegate of that signature.

Comment: Yuck... please, don't define events that return a value. Follow the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/event).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following pattern by leveraging [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class EventEmitter
{
    public event Func<bool> FooEvent;
    public EventEmitter()
    {
        //....
    }

    private void Emit()
    {
        var handlers = FooEvent.GetInvocationList();
        foreach (Func<bool> handler in handlers)
        {
            var result = handler();
            if (!result)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the order of the invocation list is in order of registration, but this is an implementation detail that you *probably* shouldn't rely on, especially as event registration [can be overridden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add).